# Way to pass an Integer array/texture to unity shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shaderlab

I'm trying to achieve rendering of cell-based terrain (one like in old games like Transport Tycoon) with strong cell borders. To optimize performance I pass a texture with an actual game map in which I try to encode a cell type for a custom shader, so the shader could lookup the type for every cell and determine which textures to apply to a particular cell while rendering the terrain mesh.

It would be convenient to pass that map in an integer type so I could mask particular bits with bitwise operators and basically pass a lot of data in just one byte. Passing floats leads to losing precision and I can't be sure I have the same integer after converting to a float and back to int.

Is there any way to pass an array (2d array or even texture is better) of Integer type to a shader or there's a reason they don't have SetIntegerArray in API like lack of compatibility with mobile GPU or something?

Answer (score 0):

Integer are not recommended to use because:

> Depending on the platform, integer types might not be supported by the
>   GPU. For example, Direct3D 9 and OpenGL ES 2.0 GPUs only operate on
>   floating point data, and simple-looking integer expressions (involving
>   bit or logical operations) might be emulated using fairly complicated
>   floating point math instructions.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DataTypesAndPrecision.html

So you must use floating point types. Use `Material.SetFloatArray()` or `Material.SetVectorArray()` for assigning.

Comment: Does this mean, that I can't cast values to integer inside the shader and apply any bitwise logic on mobile GPUs?

Comment: Of course you can, but you have no guarantee that code wil be executed on all devices.